# How do I create real time ticker graph from AWS kinesis data stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

How can I create a real time graph ticker updating every 2-3 secs just like NASDAQ for data streams coming from my AWS Kinesis Firehose to AWS Kinesis Analytics? How do I get the output from Kinesis Analytics? Trying to achieve something close to this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

We did something similar. One possible solution for your use case:

- Configure an [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) cluster.
- Use a Kinesis to Elasticsearch [connector](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors). This will take care of automatically flowing your data from Kinesis to ES.
- Use [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) to visualize your ES data. It allows configuring the refresh interval and creating dashboards.

You might have to put some effort in setting up Elasticsearch. But it is all open-source, and so is Kibana.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ketan! Still working on Elastic-search connector.